# How do I design a database schema to compute IOU for two regions (coordinates)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

**Short Question**

I want to store coordinates of multiple polygons (regions) in a postgres database. What I would need is to be able to get is all region pairs which have an IOU (Intersection Over Union) > 0.5 (any value). If one region has more than one matching regions, pick the one with the highest IOU.

It would be very helpful if someone can give me the approach on how the schema should be and what kind of SQL queries would be needed to achieve this.

**Long Question**

Context: Users and AI models add annotations on files (images) in our platform. Let's say AI draws 2 boxes on an image. Box1 with label l1 and Box2 with label l2. User draws 1 box on the same image named Box3 with label l1.

There could be millions of such files and we want to compute various detection and classification metrics from the above information.

Detection metrics would be based on if the box detected by AI matches the user's box or not. We rely on IOU to understand if 2 boxes match or not.
Classification metrics would be on top of those boxes which are determined to be correct based on the IOU by checking if label given by user is there in the labels given by AI.

I want an approach on what kind of DB schema should be used for this kinds of problem statements and how complex the SQL queries would be in terms of performance

Comment: In terms of functionalities, have a look at PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks @JGH, I will have a look at the PostGIS extension